# Optimize QuartzCore Animation with Shadows and Rasterization

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, animation, uiview, quartz-core

Within my iOS app, I have a [uiview](/questions/tagged/uiview) that needs to be animated, transformed with gestures, shaded (using [quartzcore](/questions/tagged/quartzcore) shadows), and edited. When I perform animations and gestures on this `UIView` it is extremely "laggy". The animations aren't very "laggy" on the iPhone, however when using the iPad the animations become almost unresponsive (to the point where it seems like my app is crashing). I've tested my app using Instruments, and the app isn't taking up much memory / CPU / power until the animations begin. I have tested both on the device and on my Intel i7 8GB iMac and the animations are "laggy" on both.

The animation I am performing is nothing complex, it is simply a translation across the X Axis. After looking through every line of code related to the animation, I found that these lines are the issue(s):

```
viewer.layer.masksToBounds = NO;
viewer.layer.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(-1, 1);
viewer.layer.shadowRadius = 3;
viewer.layer.shadowOpacity = 0.3;
```

The above code adds a shadow to the view that lags whenever I animate it (`viewer`). If I use the above code, but I add the following line animations work nicely:

```
viewer.layer.shouldRasterize = YES;
```

The problem with this code is that is seriously decreases the quality of the content displayed inside of the UIView (`viewer`). Here's an image with `shouldRasterize` set to YES:

[image: UIView with Rasterization]

Then the UIView without `shouldRasterize`:

[image: UIView without Rasterization]

Those screenshots are both from the same Retina iPad.

**The ultimate question**: How can I smoothly perform animations on a `UIView` with shadows (preferably using `QuartzCore`)? Is there a way to rasterize the content without degrading its quality?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The shadow properties on `CALayer` can be very inefficient while animating because it requires recalculating the shadow on every frame based on the contents of the layer. Luckily, the expensive part is the shadow path calculation, so if you just create a `CGPath` representing the shape of your content and assign it to `layer.shadowPath` then performance will skyrocket.

Since your layer seems to be completely filled with opaque data, the `shadowPath` is pretty simple:

```
layer.shadowPath = [UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:(CGRect){CGPointZero, layer.bounds.size}].CGPath;
```

The only downside is you'll need to edit this whenever the size of the layer changes.

Comment: This works great, but what method should I use to update the shadow size? I think I'll have to store the shadow in an ivar and access it later from another method, correct?

Comment: @RazorSharp: Why would you store it? Just remember that if you change the size of the view, then you need to update the shadow too. It's obviously trivially calculable from the view's frame.

Comment: True, my code is setup in the `viewDidLoad` and I was thinking it might be efficient to change it in some kind of redraw method but I couldn't think of what that method was (I know there's one on OSX)